# ActiveForm, possible to alter a combobox on active form

Tags: c#, forms, combobox

if I have an active form I am able to do this:

```
Form form = TicketAssignment.ActiveForm; // This form has a combobox on it.
```

Now, my question is, is it possible to add items to the combobox on this form using the variable I just assigned above?

Comment: Yes ! it is possible

Comment: what happens when you try?  are you getting an error?  why do you ask?

Comment: I'm asking because I need that functionality but wasn't sure how to do it.  Actually, I wound up using a public event to handle the combobox update.  But if the Form also works I'll compare efficiency and go with the better! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if the combobox or the data object it is bound to are public properties on the form.
You could then modify the items by either using form.ComboBox1.Items or form.DataObject...